# r -bootstrap for trimmed mean

Tags: r, statistics

I have a vector from an unknown distribution of which we wish to estimate the mean  through the trimmed mean.

```
vec=c(5, 4, 9, 6, 21, 17, 11, 20, 7, 10, 21, 15, 13, 16, 8)
```

How can I estimate the probability density function of the trimmed mean (estimator of μ)
using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to bootstrap the trimmed mean of the vector `vec`.
Define a function to compute the bootstrapped values, with an argument `trim` to make it more flexible. Then use function `boot` from base package `boot` to call the function.

The mean value of the bootstrap values is the estimator you want.

```
stat <- function(x, i, trim){
  mean(x[i], trim = trim)
}

R <- 1e3
set.seed(2022)
bmean <- boot::boot(vec, stat, R = R, trim = 0.1)

mean(bmean$t)
#[1] 12.12523

d <- density(bmean$t)
hist(bmean$t, freq = FALSE)
lines(d)
```